# What is the meaning of "I'm a wiener"?

Tags: meaning, expressions, jokes, offensive-language

I have scoured out dictionaries searching for the word wiener without success. As you can notice I am not a native speaker.
I usually see the this phrase as a demeaning joke on animations when some character is lured to say one's name when actually it turns out as something stupid like "I'm a wiener" or "I. C. Wiener".

Can someone say where is the joke on it? Because it sounds to me like "winner", what is not a demeaning word, reather it comes as a comendation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I. C. Wiener = icy wiener, the latter literally "sausage" but slang for penis.  (Of course "penis" itself is quite the euphemism treadmill over the years, with hundreds if not thousands of terms; even the word itself comes from a Latin euphemism, literally "tail".)

It's juvenile rather than demeaning as such.  Note also the connection with "dick", which means both "penis" and "jerk, contemptible person".

Comment: I will add that *wiener* comes from *Wien* (German for *Vienna*), so it is not related to *winner*.

Comment: And what about the "I'm a winner" expression? What it means? Has it the same meaning?

Comment: @Claudio Junior: I don't really hear people say that.  I suppose if someone said "I'm a winner" I would think that they won some competition.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry, I typed wrong. I saw written "I'm a wiener". This is my doubt.

Comment: @Claudio Junior: I haven't heard that either, but it would be interpreted as "I'm a dick" in the latter sense above, that is, loosely, 'I'm a bad person'.

Comment: @RegDwight and so probably a good job that JFK didn't give his famous "Ich bin ein Berliner" speech in the Austrian capital.

Comment: @mgb - Or the French one, as the joke ran in Berlin, where a *parisienne* is a condom.

Comment: @Malvolio - and the important distinction between a "French man of letters", and "a man of french letters"